# How to get Store logo and image alt in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to get store logo and logo alt tag and homepage URL of store through to store id. I am using below code but its not working for me.

```
        $storeid=1;

        $store['id']=$collections->getStore_id();   
        $store['image']=Mage::app()->getStore($storeid)->getLogoSrc();
        $store['alt']=Mage::app()->getStore($storeid)->getLogoAlt();
        $store['storeurl']=Mage::app()->getStore($storeid)->getHomeUrl();
```

In return i am getting

```
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Default Store View
        [image] => 
        [alt] => 
        [storeurl] =>
```

Let me know where i am doing wrong or how to get store logo and logo alt tag and homepage URL from store ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get this with below code all detail is store in table **core_config_data** so you use this

```
  $logo_src =   Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/logo_src', $store_id)


  $logo_alt =   Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/logo_alt', $store_id)
```

you may verify with header.php block function

with below function

**class Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header**

```
public function getLogoSrc()
    {
        if (empty($this->_data['logo_src'])) {
            $this->_data['logo_src'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/logo_src');
        }
        return $this->getSkinUrl($this->_data['logo_src']);
    }

    public function getLogoAlt()
    {
        if (empty($this->_data['logo_alt'])) {
            $this->_data['logo_alt'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/logo_alt');
        }
        return $this->_data['logo_alt'];
    }
```

hope this will sure help you